# Can I access program arguments from a post-run action?

Tags: xcode

I use Xcode to build a program that generates a lot of unprocessed output. Xcode supports post-run actions, and I would like to use one to trigger some processing on that output.

That program generates its output at a location determined by command-line parameters. Can these parameters be accessed by post-run actions?